# Clarify about pullback of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a ring and let $I\subseteq A$ an ideal such that $V(I)$ doesn't contain any irreducible component of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. Call $R$ the subring of the product $A\times A$ defined as $R:=\{(x,y)\in A\times A:(x-y\in I)\}$. Show that $R$ is finite as an $A$-module.

Now, it could be that not all the  hypothesis are strictly necessary, because this is the very first part of a more complex exercise. Anyway, $R$ is isomorphic to $A\times I$ as $A$-modules, so I would say that it is finite if and only if $I$ is a finitely generated ideal: in fact if $A\times I$ is generated by $(a_1,i_1),\dots,(a_n,i_n)$, then $i_1,\dots,i_n$ generate $I$, while if $i_1,\dots,i_n$ generate $I$, $A\times I$ is generated by $(1,0),(0,i_1),\dots,(0,i_n)$. So it seems to me that I should prove that $I$ is finitely generated. However it doesn't seem, in general, that if $V(I)$ doesn't contain any irreducible component $I$ is finitely generated. For example, in $k[X_1,X_2,\dots]$ the only minimal prime is $(0)$; if we set $I=(X_1,X_2,\dots)$, it is not finitely generated but $V(I)\subsetneq\operatorname{Spec}A$, so it doesn't contain the unique irreducible component. Thanks in advance for any clarify

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the [prior edition of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329096/if-vi-doesnt-contain-irreducible-components-is-it-finitely-generated#comment9026639_4329096) which you deleted right before asking this one, your counterexample is correct and the exercise is wrong.

Comment: I deleted it because it made a reference to another question that has been closed, I don't see why